# How to manipulate specific condition in some colums by pandas

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements

I've question about how to manipulate specific condtion in some colums.

For example,

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

df = DataFrame({'name' : ['apple','pineapple','melon','orange','mango','durian'],
            'amt' : [200,300,100,1,3,120]},
             index = ['1','2','3','4','5','6'])

print(df)
```

I can see,

```
   amt       name
1  200      apple
2  300  pineapple
3  100      melon
4    1     orange
5    3      mango 
6  120     durian
```

From above result I want to manipulate amt of apple with other items hold.
I just only know...

```
df.loc[df.name.str.contains('apple'), 'amt'] = df['amt']/100
```

This syntax manipulates not only 'apple' but 'pineapple'.
I'd like to get only result revising apple's amt like...

```
   amt       name
1    2      apple
2  300  pineapple
3  100      melon
4    1     orange
5    3      mango 
6  120     durian
```

Is there anyone help me?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Just take the .str.cointains and go straight to df.name == 'apple'. it's not hard to understand that contains actually will take any string that has 'apple' in it, including pineapple

Comment: you almost had it:  `df.loc[df.name=='apple','amt'] = df.amt / 100`